# How to implement Text Wrap such that it adjusts the position of adjacent controls to the bottom accordingly?

Tags: c#, text, word-wrap

Sorry if I'm not being clear. I'm not sure how else to pose this question. Anyway, I have a textblock which has its `TextWrapping` property set to `Wrap` and I have another textblock exactly below it which represents another entity. What I would like to achieve is that if the text in the first textblock Wraps to two or three lines, the next textblock should adjust its position accordingly exactly below it.

In short:

> If the text does not overflow then the layout should be like this

[image: pic1]

> If it does overflow to wrap the control, I would like the next control below it to adjust its postion accrodingly like this:

[image]

Comment: can you not code `Environment.NewLine();` in your existing code..?

Comment: I don't understand. Using a StackPanel for the TextBlocks will solve the problem automatically.

Comment: Well, yea maybe isn't it! I kind of knew this! Just missed my mind!  Hopefully it will!

Comment: @DJKRAZE I have two TextBlocks not just one!

Comment: is this C# Winforms or WPF..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a StackPanel, duh uh!
Thanks to @Fratyx